# Search function with unknown indata

Tags: c#, linq, search

I'd like to make a search function that takes indata from 5 textboxes, Name, gender,ID, animal category and animal. The diffrances between animal category and animal is for eg. animal category = mammal and animal = bear.
So these are optional to the user, when he/she hits the button it should search for the given parameters.
The data is saved in an genereic list with the Animal type. eg. ListanimalCollection

I tried to use linq, my query ->

```
    ienumerable<Animal> result= 
    from a in animalCollection where a.Name== myParameterName
    &&
    a.Gender == myParameterGender
    select a;
```

the problem comes to when user wants to have one or more than two parameters cus i don't know how to make the query depending on user input.
Do i have to make a bunch of if-statements to check user input? I hope there is another way!

Im asking you smart experts for help with this! Hope i made myself clear enough.

Daniel, sweden

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your parameters are all strings then you could do something like this:

```
var result = from a in animalCollection
             where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myParameterName) || a.Name == myParameterName)
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myParameterGender) || a.Gender == myParameterGender)
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myParameterID) || a.ID == myParameterID)
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myParameterCategory) || a.Category == myParameterCategory)
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myParameterAnimal) || a.Animal == myParameterAnimal)
             select a;
```

Comment: LukeH, Thank you for you quick respons.
I tried your query and it does not work when one of the parameters is empty.
eg, name="" and gender = female.
Im out of sugestions, been trying to figure this out for quite some time now.

Daniel

Comment: @Daniel: It should work in that situation. What happens? Do you get an error? Does the query return no results? Unexpected results?

Comment: You are totaly awesome!
It really worked! Im so glad! I've spent like two days on trying for a good solution! This was exactly what i as looking for.
Im sorry for accusing your solution to be wrong, i've tried so many.
This is very nice!! Just a couple of rows! Awesome!
So now the my search function works very well thanks to you!

Just one question about this query...
eg. (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myParameterName) || a.Name == myParameterName)
How does this query work? If string.IsNullOrEmpty gets a match first, then it should not look up the name? Am i right? If false, then look up the name...

Comment: @Daniel: Exactly. So if, for example, you only supply `myParameterID` then the query would be roughly equivalent to `...where true && true && (a.ID == myParameterID) && true && true...`

Comment: Okay! Im not sure that i really get it completly, allthough id like to. 
In the (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myParameterName) || a.Name == myParameterName)
If the parameter is empty, then IsNullOrEmpty should return false, right? And a.Name == nameParameter should also return false then because it expects atleast some characters.
So then (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myParameterName) || a.Name == myParameterName) would be (false || false). Allthough! One of those statements have to return true or otherwise the query would not continue to look for input in the other parameters, gender, id, cat and animal.

Comment: @Daniel: No. If the parameter is *null* or *empty* then `string.IsNullOrEmpty` returns `true`, in which case the second part of the clause -- checking the property against the parameter -- doesn't get evaluated.